# My date range comparison isnt working?

Tags: c#

Okay target date: 12/16/15 should return true. It's not.

```
 public bool IsBlockedDay(DateTime dtDate)
    {
        DateTime block1Start = new DateTime(dtDate.Year, 12, 16); //Dec 16
        DateTime block1End = new DateTime(dtDate.Year, 1, 14); //Jan 14

        DateTime block2Start = new DateTime(dtDate.Year, 5, 15); // May 16
        DateTime block2End = new DateTime(dtDate.Year, 8, 14); // Aug 14

       // dateTocheck >= startDate && dateToCheck <= endDate

        if (dtDate >= block1Start && dtDate <= block1End)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (dtDate >= block2Start && dtDate <= block2End)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

When I evaluate this function, 12/16/15 returns false for whatever reason. It's driving me bonkers... Anyone else see this?

Comment: 12/16/15 as in 16th of december 2015? What date format is that?

Comment: You're effectively saying "When 12/16/15 is equal to or after 12/16/15 AND 12/16/15 is equal to or before 14/01/15, return true". This will never be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your block 1 start and end are backwards. Try this:

```
    DateTime block1Start = new DateTime(dtDate.Year, 1, 14); //Jan 14
    DateTime block1End = new DateTime(dtDate.Year, 12, 16); //Dec 16
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one to the year when you create your block 1 end. So, like:

```
DateTime block1End = new DateTime(dtDate.Year + 1, 1, 14); //Jan 14
```

Because right now your block1End is January 14, 2015. And so when you compare December 16, 2015, `dtDate >= block1Start` is true, but `dtDate <= block1End` is false since December 16, 2015 is not less than January 14, 2015. And so, your method returns false. Applying the fix above should make it return what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I think today im coding too fast. Didnt obviously see it , but I ran each conditional and seen that was the case. I ended up editing:

 DateTime block1End = new DateTime(dtDate.AddYears(1).Year, 1, 14); //Jan 14

Comment: Okay, great! Please mark as answer if this was helpful to you. :)